# Class IMAActivityMonitor is implemented in both 'framework' and 'targetApp', One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, google-ima

I'm making a video player framework which uses GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK to play ads.
And have pod file like this

```
target 'targetApp' do
  #do nothing about Google IMA
end

target 'myFramework' do
  pod  'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'
end
```

I know the log won't lead my app crash or broken. But the log msg just make me so furious... I'm digging this problem for days, but nothing progress.

I'm also use `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` to link other framework which used by my `targetApp` and `myFramework` and everything is just fine (I don't receive the warning `other framework is implemented both my targetApp and myFramework`).However when I use this method to link GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK, I still get the log msg... It make me so frustrated.

Should I just leave the log msg alone, or something I can try to solve this problem? I've looked [other framework](https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios-ima) but still don't know how to solve this.

Maybe it is more reasonable to divide the player & ads, just write a extension to communicate each other?